# Pass environment variable values to spring boot profiles (application.properties file) when deploying from Github

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, github, google-app-engine, environment-variables

I have a simple Spring Boot REST app that uses Mongo Atlas as the database and I have a couple of environment variables to pass to the project for the connection URL. I have defined this in the src/main/resources/application.properties which is the standard Spring profile for storing such properties. Here's the property name and value.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://${mongodb.username}:${mongodb.password}@....

I use VSCode for local dev and use a launch.json file which is not committed to my github repo to pass these values and I can run this locally. I was able to deploy this app successfully to Heroku and setup these two values in the Heroku console in my App settings and it all works fine on Heroku also. I am trying to deploy the same app to GCP App Engine but I could not find an easy way to pass these values. All the help articles seem to indicate that I need to use some gcp datastore and some cloud provider specific code in my app. Or use some kind of a github action script. That seems a little bit involved and I wanted to know if there is an easy way of passing these values to the app via gcp settings (just like in Heroku) without polluting my repo with cloud provider specific code or yml files.

Comment: Problem is to pass these specific environment variables in the application.properties file to a Spring Boot app deployed on GCP App Engine from Github. 
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://${mongodb.username}:${mongodb.password}@....

Comment: I am able to find one way of passing these arguments by creating an inline cloudbuild.yaml file in the CloudBuild trigger.
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn
    entrypoint: mvn
    args: ["install", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true"]
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn
    entrypoint: mvn
    args: ["spring-boot:run", "-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--mongodb.username=<username> --mongodb.password=<password>"]
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY

Comment: The build completes successfully and the app is starting up but the build status just keeps showing running. When I try to connect to https://<project-id>.appspot.com I get 404